# Why does blowing air on wet bodies dry it?

Tags: thermodynamics, flow, air, evaporation

Suppose I blow dry a region with some water on it. Would it dry it faster than otherwise? If yes, why?

I can give one qualitative reason against it, since the blow dryer is  blowing room temperature air, no real heating is done on the hair.

But perhaps there are some effects I'm not considering, so some more authortative answers would be appreciated.

[Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127522/236734)

Comment: the air jus above the moisture  is saturated with  water vapor, th air from the blower is dry, so it will take the vaposr away and new vapor can evaporate.

Comment: possible duplicate:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298017/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some clarification.

when water evaporates from a surface in the absence of air movement, the air right next to the surface becomes saturated with water vapor and the rate of evaporation slows towards zero.

By stirring up the air next to the surface, you are providing the surface with a fresh supply of dry air into which the water will readily dissolve. Then the air movement carries away the air containing vapor, and replaces it with dry air.

This action maximizes the evaporation rate.

Answer (score 4):

The water evaporates constantly. Blowing air around the drying body ensures that the air near the surface of the body isn't saturated with water - otherwise there would too many water particles in the air for the new ones to evaporate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).